# Retain .asp URL Extensions in new ASPX Website

Tags: asp.net

Hi guys I am working with some ASP developers that are converting our classic ASP website over to ASPX. My job is mainly SEO and I have informed them that changing our URL structure can/will severely affect our website negatively.

However, our developers insist that there is nothing that can be done to retain our old .asp extensions.

For example, a URI on our current site looks like this - example.com/t-shirts.asp but they plan to change this URI to example.com/t-shirts.aspx.

Is there a way that we can retain our original .asp extensions in aspx? Redirecting our old pages to new .aspx ones will cause major SEO problems, and organic traffic is extremely important to us.

Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. You can use routing. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series